# Use JTable entries as buttons

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable which contains names returned from a search in database. I want to use the names as buttons, when we click on them the program redirect to another frame with more details of the nameholder. Can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do, add the mouse listener to the table and use [columnAtPoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#columnAtPoint%28java.awt.Point%29) and `rowAtPoint` to determine what has been clicked.

If you want a table cell to look like a button, [set a renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setCellRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer%29) that uses `JButton`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use the names as buttons, when we click on them the program redirect to another frame with more details of the nameholder.

You need to create a custom renderer and editor for your table. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for basic information.

Then you can check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) which is an example of a render/editor that you can use. You will need to provide your own custom `Action` to display the details.